# Binding DataGrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I'm trying to bind DataGrid to understand binding. While binding normal TextBoxes and Blocks is extremely easy, DataGrid creates problems.

My sample code:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        PeopleView people = new PeopleView();
        ObservableCollection<Person> list = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            list.Add(new Person
            {
                Name = "AA",
                Surname = "BB"
            });

            people.People = list;

            DataContext = people;
        }
    }

    public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }

    public class PeopleView : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Person> People { get; set; }
        public Person Selected { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

I'm using PropertyChanged.Fody, so no need to implement anything else beside interface.

XAML:

```xml
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding people}"></DataGrid>
```

Everything seems fine, but after launching program DataGrid is empty. Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Should be `ItemsSource="{Binding People}"`. You should have seen a data binding error message in the Output Window in Visual Studio. I'd also recommend not to call a view model "XyzView".

Comment: This did the trick, thank you. It's just a sample. i believe it should be called "XViewModel". Also managed to get selected item (thats why i needed Selected property).